What is the best practice to use dynamic names/variables in the sdf files?
NOTE: This is an open discussion and might not have a particular answer or can have multiple answers.
Hello,
I was trying to do a multi-robot simulation using ROS 2 humble and GZ-harmonic.
I want to create the number of robot instances dynamically from the argument in the launch file. I also have some plugins where I need to specify the namespace, as it does not take a model name as a namespace prefix.
I found an example on the aerostack that uses the jinja format. (I did not try it)
Another lazy way I tried is to replace the matching string that I put in the my_robot.sdf (which is TopicNS in the example below) dynamically while spawning the model using -string. (example below)
Which works quite well.
Just want to discuss which is the better approach or if there is some other suggestion on this topic from the community.
sdf_file = os.path.join(
        pkg_project_gazebo, "models", "my_robot", "my_robot.sdf"
    )

with open(sdf_file, "r") as infp:
        robot_desc = infp.read()

gz_spawn = []
bridge_topics = []
for i in range(1, nb_robots): #nb_robots are coming from launch arguments
    bridge_topics.append(f"/robot_{i}/cmd_vel@geometry_msgs/msg/Twist@gz.msgs.Twist")
    gz_spawn.append(Node(
        package="ros_gz_sim",
        executable="create",
        output='screen',
        arguments=[
            "-world",
            "factory",
            "-allow_renaming",
            "true",
            "-name",
            f"robot_{i}",
            "-string",
            robot_desc.replace("TopicNS",f"robot_{i}"),
            "-x",
            f"{(i-1)*1}",
            "-y",
            "0",
            "-z",
            "0",
        ],
    ))
bridge = Node(
        package="ros_gz_bridge",
        executable="parameter_bridge",
        parameters=[
            {
                "config_file": os.path.join(
                    pkg_project_gazebo, "config", "demo.yaml"
                ),
                "qos_overrides./tf_static.publisher.durability": "transient_local",
            }
        ],
        arguments=bridge_topics, # pass all created bridge topics here
        output="screen",
    )

return LaunchDescription(
    [
    gz_sim,
    bridge,
    # other nodes
    ] + gz_spawn


I'm afraid that questions which ask about the Pros/cons or Advantages/disadvantages are effectively opinion polls, which are discouraged on stack exchange. We prefer practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face, so questions which ask for a list of advantages & disadvantages for different options are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Hello @MarkBooth, yes I know that but this is not well documented anywhere so I thought posting here might help someone in future while improving the answer. I could have done answer my own qn without putting as discussion but I just want to explore options here.

Rather than asking to discuss best practice it's better to ask how to do something. If you get one answer and it's voted up lots, you can be pretty sure it's best practice. If you get lots of different answers, and none pull ahead, you can be certain that there is no consensus on best practice. Ultimately, we are not a discussion forum, we are a place to ask questions and get answers. If you wish to discuss a question or answer you can use [chat], since you already have chat privileges.

Another (probably better than replacing string) solution that I found is to use a built-in Python3.x template functionality from the string. It is kind of similar to Jinja.
For an example,
Part of the sdf file I copied from aerostack2 is used here.
<plugin
        filename="ignition-gazebo-multicopter-motor-model-system"
        name="ignition::gazebo::systems::MulticopterMotorModel">
        
        <!--It is important to leave a space after the tag-->
        <robotNamespace>model/$namespace </robotNamespace>
        
        <jointName>rotor_0_joint</jointName>
        <linkName>rotor_0</linkName>
        <!--
        Not much important part for this question
        -->
</plugin>

A modified launch file can look something like this. You can also use a yaml or json file to store the variable in there and change it dynamically using a Python launch file.
from string import Template
gz_spawn = []
bridge_topics = []
rd_template = Template(robot_desc) # convert string in template
for i in range(1, 3):
    bridge_topics.append(f"/robot_{i}/cmd_vel@geometry_msgs/msg/Twist@gz.msgs.Twist")
    gz_spawn.append(Node(
        package="ros_gz_sim",
        executable="create",
        output='screen',
        arguments=[
            "-world",
            "factory",
            "-allow_renaming",
            "true",
            "-name",
            f"robot_{i}",
            "-string",
            rd_template.substitute(namespace=f"robot_{i}"),
            "-x",
            f"{(i-1)*1}",
            "-y",
            "0",
            "-z",
            "1",
        ],
    ))


Per a recent working group discussion for Gazebo, where the
AeroStack Jinja solution was presented, this was the agreed upon recommendation for the time being, and endorsed by the Gazebo maintainers as a good approach.
Keep in mind that sdformat also supports environment variables.
I would not recommend string replace as that is easy to break.
Reference: https://community.gazebosim.org/t/community-meeting-from-gazebo-simulation-to-wind-turbine-inspections-powered-by-aerostack2/2474
